# LINQ Group by with sort

Tags: c#, linq

I know I could do this outside of a LINQ query, but I wondered if it was possible to do so within one.

I would like to submit a query where I'm retrieving the most recent item with a distinct ID associated with it.

Say I have the following objects:

```
{
    ItemDescription: 'Object 1',
    ItemDate: 1/1/2016,
    ItemTypeId: 1
},
{
    ItemDescription: 'Object 2',
    ItemDate: 1/1/2016,
    ItemTypeId: 2
},
{
    ItemDescription: 'Object 3',
    ItemDate: 3/1/2016,
    ItemTypeId: 1
},
```

I would like a query to return objects 2 and 3 (since 3 was a more recent version of `ItemTypeId=1`.

It should (I think) be something like the following:

```
var recentItems = (from s in db
                   orderby s.ItemDate descending
                   group s by s.ItemTypeId into uniqueItems
                   select uniqueItems.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

However, the `FirstOrDefault` overrides the ordering.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var recentItems = (from s in db
                   group s by s.ItemTypeId into uniqueItems
                   select uniqueItems.OrderByDescending(x=> x.ItemDate ).FirstOrDefault())
                                                                        .ToList();
```